# Ajax.BeginForm render wrong url in mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to load a div data using ajax rather than whole view on post method.
but it returns `object%20HTMLInputElement` action name on post action.

## Controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
   return View();
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(DemoCLass objdemo)
 {
   return View();
 }
```

## View

```
<div id="divEmp">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Challan", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "divEmp" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h3 style="text-align:center;" class="row header">Challan Data</h3>

    @Html.Partial("_DateCommonFT")
            }
```

It includes `_Layout.cshtml` where i have defined scripts as:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

How to render only post action without loading whole page (_layout.cshtml) on post request using ajax.

Comment: Sorry ! What is the problem you are facing ? I am still having trouble understanding your current and expected behavior.

Comment: close your div tag like <div id="divEmp"></div>

Comment: @Priya Update your question with the error message/unexpected behaviour and the expected output.

Comment: @Priya did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to close your div tag and receive `HtmlForgeryToken` in controller like following.

you can also fill your target div with PartialView by returning `PartialView()` in `Index` method

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(DemoCLass objdemo)
{
   return PartialView();
}


<div id="divEmp">
</div>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Challan", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "divEmp" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h3 style="text-align:center;" class="row header">Challan Data</h3>

    @Html.Partial("_DateCommonFT")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please Ajax.Begin form you can use OnSuccess method.

**In VIew:-**

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Challan", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "divEmp",  OnSuccess = "AjaxForm" }))
    {
    }
```

**In Script:-**
here return json from post controller.

```
function AjaxForm(response){
.....do as uou want...
}
```

**in Controller:-**

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(DemoCLass objdemo)
 {
   return json(new {IsSuccess = true},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

if you have any query in this one then tell to me

Answer (score 0):

Use the `PartialView` method to return a view without the layout.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(DemoCLass objdemo)
{
   return PartialView();
}
```

If you want to return the html without layout markup only for the ajax form submissions, you can check the request headers to see whether the request is an xhr request or not. `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` method will be handy here.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(DemoCLass objdemo)
{
   if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
   {
      return PartialView();
   }
   else
   {
      return View();
   }
}
```

Comment: What if my ajax post is not hitting on controller post method ? it is going on wrong url `object%20HTMLInputElement`

Comment: Check the view source of the page and see why it is generating a wrong action attribute value for the form. My assumption is that the code rendered by `_DateCommonFT` partial view is breaking the markup. can you try to comment out that and try ? That will help you isolate the issue

Comment: I have checked by commenting that partial view, included only a button for controlling post action. but no luck.. rendering on `object%20HTMLInputElement`

Comment: I hope you fixed the missing closing tag of your div "divEmp". I tried (only) the code you posted in the question and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @Shyju I think OP also miss [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] in controller